# Add optional operation to Qt Installer

Tags: qt, qt-installer

I'm creating a fairly straightforward offline installer for my product using the Qt Installer Framework (v3.0).

The product includes a driver installer for a Sentinel HASP protection key. Ideally I would like to present the user with an option to skip running this driver installer (in the case where they have already installed this driver with a previous product installation, for example), but I can't seem to find a concise example in the QtIFW documentation of the best/simplest way to achieve this.

The size of the driver is relatively tiny compared to the size of the main product package, so there's no concern with always including the file.

Answer (score 0):

Let we have driver-installer.exe that installs that driver.

If you want to make its execution optional you can add failed return code as accepted return code for this execution like below

> component.addOperation("Execute", {0,xxx}, "driver-installer.exe");

Here xxx should be replaced with your failed return code

Comment: (apologies for late comment) I think this assumes that driver-installer is interactive and can be cancelled by the user when it's run. In my case the driver installer is a non-interactive CL utility, so I need to be able to ask the user from the Qt installer so that the driver installer exe can be skipped entirely.

Comment: You can add option to Install/Skip driver at module selection page or any other custom page, and on the basis of user selection take decision to add/skip driver installation operation to installer.

Comment: For reference you can visit https://github.com/anilagrawal038/qt-installer